# Positioning a div to the right using relative

Tags: css, css-position, positioning

My CSS:

```
   .topLogoContainer{
        margin-top: 2%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
        background-color: #660066;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .topLogoText{
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    p.topButton{
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
```

my HTML:

```
<div class="topLogoContainer">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="topLogoText">
                <font size="18">TB's Jewelry</font>
            </td><td>
                <a href="buy.php" class="topButton">
                    <div class="topButton2">
                        <p class="topButton">buy</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a top bar of a website (let's call it "Tbar") (you know, where the logo and navigation buttons go), and I want the main text at the left, vertically center inside Tbar (of course, make it look nice and give it some margin/padding) while making 2 buttons (which are round colored divs that are links) at the very bottom of, in the right inner part of Tbar. I think I need the buttons to be relative, so it will always be inside Tbar. Trying "position: relative; right: 10px; bottom: 0px;" doesn't do what I want - since it doesn't move it to the inner right of Tbar.

Javascript seems ridiculous to use, and I'm not well practiced on it.

Comment: float:right? jsfiddle example ? btw. I hope you're not serious about using TABLES for navbar

Answer (score 0):

Some good practices:

- Avoid adding elements like `p` or `div` inside your `a` tag.
- This is a simple layout so mixing `div` with `table` is not necessary.
- Using percentage for your div's `height` may not work.

Below is a working example. Try changing the `height` of your `.topLogoContainer` div to fit with your need.

```css
.topLogoContainer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #660066;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.topLogoText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 9pt);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding: 10px;
}
.linkContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
.topButton {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topLogoContainer">
  <div class="topLogoText">TB's Jewelry</div>
  <div class="linkContainer">
    <a href="buy.php" class="topButton">something else</a>
    <a href="buy.php" class="topButton">buy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```